# CoreData fetch speed affected by number of parameters in NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to figure out a way to optimize some of my CoreData fetch requests.  I currently have NSPredicates that have 2 or 3 parameters to search on.  They are all indexed.

Is is faster to have a single index I can search on or several I can search against?  Also are indexes against int's faster than say an index against a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What certainly helps is to make sure to select records that discriminate the most first. For example selecting only a couple of records with a certain keyvalue is very much faster (with an index available) than selecting all active records if 90 % of the records is active AND selecting something else at the same time. In this case you should probably be even off better be removing the index on the non discriminating field to make sure the index on the disciminating field is used.

Also, a predicate with an or statement will be a lot slower than one without. 
Selecting on integers will be faster than selecting on strings, but if both are indexed the difference will be small.

Selecting on a keypath instead of a key also negatively affects performance.
(One example I recently used, predicate:

```
product.subgroup.code == %@
```

Selects from 150.000 products the right ones in a glitch (within 0.1 sec), while:

```
product.subgroup.maingroup.code == %@
```

Selects from 150.000 products the right ones in about 1.5 sec

In core data you can only tell a single attribute to be indexed in the data model editor. In real SQL databases, you would index on several attributes at once. Afaik, no index advisor can be used in core-data.

Testing with a real-life database in instruments (use the instrument for core data fetches) will help you find the bottlenecks and probably the best answer for you case.

Comment: I have a bunch of my attributes marked as indexed?  So is only 1 really being indexed?  This might be the root of my problem.

Comment: They are separately indexed, but the optimizer can only use 1 index per fetchRequest